# use of array of structs in c#

Tags: c#, struct

I need help about array of structs initiliazation. In a code something like below, how we can accomplish the initiliazation defined in comment ??

```
class structExample
{
    struct state{
        int previousState;
        int currentState;
    }
     static state[] durum;

     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
         durum = new state[5];

         // how we can assign new value to durum[0].previousState = 0; doesn't work ??


     }

}
```

}

Thanks..

Comment: [Mutable structs are evil](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default accessibility for members in C# is private which is why the assignment statement is failing.  You need to make the fields accessible by having adding `internal` or `public` to them.

```
struct state{
    internal int previousState;
    internal int currentState;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

durum = new state[5]; -> creates only the array for 5 elements.

You need to initialize every element inside the array.